# How do MLP Classification using Keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, text-classification, mlp

I'm newbie in Neural Network. I'm going to do a text classification research using MLP model with keras. Input layer consisting of 900 nodes, 2 hidden layers, and 2 outputs.

The code I use is as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units = 100, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(units = 100, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid'))
opt = Adam (learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = opt, metrics = ['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

But get error:

```
This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or by calling the model on a batch of data.
```

How to fix that error? Thank you.

Comment: To run `summary()` you need to define the shape of the input data which you didn't provide.

Comment: How to define the shape of the input data?

Comment: When you define Sequential model, the first layer should take an `input_shape` parameter. For example, `Dense(units = 100, activation = 'sigmoid', input_shape=(1, 1))`